# Get dates between two days of the week using Python

Tags: python, date, beautifulsoup

I m parsing an html document using python and beautifulSoup where I get strings with the following format, i.e `workingdates = 'Wednesday-Tuesday'`.

From that point i get `startDate = 'Wednesday'` and `endDate = 'Tuesday'`.

I want to create a list with all the working days i.e `list=['Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']`

Any ideas?

Comment: What if endDate is `Friday`?

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a list of all week days

```
weekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
             'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

and having defined your start and end dates

```
startDate, endDate  = 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday'
```

you can find their positions in the `weekdays` list

```
start = weekdays.index(startDate)
end = weekdays.index(endDate)
```

there are two possible cases `start < end` and `start > end`. For the first case you simply take a normal slice. For the second you slice from `start` to the end of list and append the part from the beginning of the list up to `end`.

```
if start < end:
    lst = weekdays[start: end+1]
else:
    lst = weekdays[start:] + weekdays[:end+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using a list representing a fortnight, by finding the index of the `startDate` and the index of the first occurrence of the `endDate` **after** the `startDate`:

```
startDate="Wednesday"
endDate="Tuesday"
```

```
week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
fortnight = week * 2

start = fortnight.index(startDate)
end = fortnight.index(endDate, start + 1) + 1

workingdays = fortnight[start:end]
```

```
print(workingdays)
>>> ['Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cycle` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import cycle

startDate, endDate = 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday'

l = []
for c in cycle(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']):
    if not l and c == startDate:
        l.append(c)
    elif l and c == endDate:
        l.append(c)
        break
    elif l:
        l.append(c)

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```